# Equivalent to phpmemcacheadmin in redis

Tags: redis, memcached, monitoring

Could someone please suggest a tool like phpmemcacheadmin, who allow me to add different redis server and monitor all the stats like del/s, set/s, get/s etc.

I have more than 10 redis server right now for different projects. I want a centralized tool to monitor all these servers. I was going through with phpredmin and php-rb projects but the problem is that i am able to add only 1 server or can add master and his slave.